# Using preg_replace() To Increment a Digit in a Phrase

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

### I have looked at the "duplicate" link but I am not having any luck. Bottom of the post is what I have tried.

Hi I have seen similar questions but I haven't found a solution or I'm not implementing it correctly.

I have a text file that looks similar to as follows:

```
user1,1;user99,4;user5,8;
```

I need to match a given user and then increment the digit following the comma by +1 using `preg_replace()`. So for example, if I search on "user1", the new text should output `user1,2;user99,4;user5,8;`.

This is what I have right now but regular expressions are not my strong suit and, of course, it doesn't work.

```
$user = "user1";
$text = "user1,1;user99,4;user5,8;";

if(preg_match('/' . $user . ',\d+;/', $text)){
    $text = preg_replace('/' . $user . ',(\d+);/i', $user . ',' . ${1} + 1 . ';', $text);
}
```

The match is returning true but it is not replacing the text how I want. Also, any tips on how to improve the code so that close variations are not detected. For example, I would not want the user "uuser1" or "user11" to be matched.

### What I have tried from "duplicate" link

```
$user = "user1";
$text = "user1,1;user99,4;user5,8;";

function inc($matches) {
    return ++$matches[1];
}

// NOPE
// $text = preg_replace_callback("|$user,(\d+)|", $user . "," . "inc", $text);

// THIS DUPLICATES ALL NUMBERS EVEN THE USER1
// $text = preg_replace_callback("|(\d+)|", "inc", $text);

// THOUGHT I WAS GETTING CLOSE, IT INCREMENTED THE CORRECT NUMBER BUT IT DIDN'T HAVE THE "USER1," BEFORE IT

$text = preg_replace_callback("|" . $user . "\,(\d+)|", "inc", $text);


// NOT HAPPENING
$text = preg_replace_callback("|" . $user . "\,(\d+)|", $user . "," . "inc", $text);
```

Comment: that question you have linked to does not help me, especially since the solutions that are linked on the selected answer are no longer available. I am not sure how to tweak that to my needs which is why I created a new question.

Comment: You can't use `preg_replace()` to perform addition.  That duplicate link is fitting.  If you can't make it work, post what you tried.  `preg_replace_callback()` on the `\d+` is exactly what you want.  I'll even recommend that you merely use the fullstring match: `'/;'.$user.',\K\d+/i` with `++$m[0]`

Comment: @mickmackusa your solution was correct. Thank you.